# Use same table in a query but with different dates

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a report with This years data and Last years data. I currently changing the dates in this query:

```
SELECT TransactionDate, Source, Medium, Campaign, AdContent,
       Keyword, Country, Device, Region,
       ROUND(SUM (Revenue),2) AS Equity_Revenue,
       ROUND(SUM (Sales),2) Equity_Sales,
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([analytics.order_attribution_], TIMESTAMP('2018-02-26'), TIMESTAMP('2018-03-04')))

WHERE ReportType = 'Daily Equity Report' AND Channel = 'Email'
GROUP BY TransactionDate, Source, Medium, Campaign, AdContent,
         Keyword, Country, Device, Region,

ORDER BY Equity_Revenue DESC;
```

and changing the dates. Is it possible to add the same query underneath so that i can then change the dates and run the query once

Comment: For those of us not familiar with `TABLE_DATE_RANGE` and date partitioning, can you also tell us the name of the column(s) used in the date partition?

Comment: Tim - TABLE_DATE_RANGE is for where you have groups of table saved with the suffix in the form of  '_YYYYMMDD'.

So in Gordon's example it would select all tables between

[analytics.order_attribution_20180226] and [analytics.order_attribution_20180304]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic date ranges instead of fixed dates with `TABLE_DATE_RANGE`, this way you don't have to edit your query in order for your report to show you up-to-date information. Here's an example in LegacySQL which shows data from the last 7 days:

```
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([analytics.order_attribution_], 
DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY')))
```

You can also string two together to grab just the weeks you require, year-over-year.

If you'd like to change your quest to StandardSQL, you could do it like this, where I pull two weeks, one from last week and another for last year:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `analytics.order_attribution_*`
WHERE parse_DATE('%y%m%d', _table_suffix) 
   BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND 
   DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) OR   parse_DATE('%y%m%d', _table_suffix)
   BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 372 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 366 DAY)
```